# How do I transfer a file to a function, if it lies in internete

Tags: c#, ini

I have a file that lies on the path http://www.site.ru/config.ini

And there is someone else's code that takes a file that should be on the computer (locally).

You can of course save the file, and then pass, but I can not save the file locally (which would not be who could not work with it).

Function:

```
[DllImport ("kernel32")]
        private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString (string section, string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filePath);
```

What shall I do?

Comment: If you can't save the file locally, then there is no solution. Why can't you do this? BTW, I couldn't make sense of the parenthetical remark.

Comment: GetPrivateProfileString - takes filePath - this pathfile is locacaly. And I am just the way the Web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe downloading the file to a stream via http might be helpful.

I found an example on how to do this on [csharpfriends.com](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=115):

```
public form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    System.Net.WebClient Client = new WebClient();
    Stream strm = Client.OpenRead("http://www.csharpfriends.com");
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strm);
    string line;
    do
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        listbox1.Items.Add(line);
    }
    while (line !=null);
    strm.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you can't write a file on the machine running your program?